# Electron, canvas ruins rendering of other elements

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, electron, html-rendering

I'm making a flow-chart electron app, and I'm trying to get the lines between two objects to work, I use a canvas with a beziercurveto() inside it, but for some reason when I scroll the other objects are staying in the same place, as if they have position:fixed, but I'm pretty sure that that isn't the case because when in scroll further they start disappearing and glitching, and when I try to select them with the dev-tool, their hitbox is in the right place, but it's not being drawn their.

images:

[without scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXPz5.png),

[with scrolling, (dev-hitbox in blue)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzyhu.png)

Is this a bug in Electron?

Comment: Electron is using Chrome's layout engine. A rule of thumb is to check if it works in Chrome before asking if it works in Electron. Make a fiddle of your code.

Comment: I know, chromium right?, I did and it worked perfectly fine, but for some reason it doesn't in electron. Ehm it's quite a lot... (I tried, while pasting it in it started lagging a lot)

Comment: I've tried it with Electron (chromium), Safari, firefox and chrome and all of them work fine, except Electron,